# How Can I search if a Address Set Contains some specific Words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program where I have to check if all address in address-set contains speicific key-Word:

For Example A:

> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD47"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD48"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD70"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD71"

For Example B:

> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD47"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD48"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "XYCD70"
>
> set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "XYCD71"

in this example, the Address-set name is "ABCD45-48/70-71", so before I delete this address set completely, I need to check  that all the members for this address set must have ABCD in there name.

if they all have ABCD in there name delete entire address-set

OUTPUT for A:

> unset group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71"

else delete specific line.

OUTPUT for B:

> unset group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD47"
>
> unset group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD48"

Comment: Where are these addresses stored..in a Dataframe or in a list or it is in a text file?

Comment: I have taken the backup in a text file and using text file as reference to create the config

Comment: General algo. 1. Read the text files 2. Read it line by line using loop 3. Split each line by "" 4. Compare to get if you got "ABCD"

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear, but I will ask your question in the title. If you have a string and you like to search a sub-string you can only use

```
if substring in string:
     #do what you want to do
```

another way is to use regular expression, here the documentations [re python](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html)

next time please share your script to help everyone to understand your problem ;)

**EDIT**

```
filename = "test.text"
import re
def splitAddresses(data):
    addresses=[]
    l=[]
    pattern=re.compile("^[GROUP]+[0-9]+[:]$")
    for element in data:
        isAmatch=pattern.match(element)
        if isAmatch==None:
            l.append(element)
        else:
            addresses.append(l)
            l=[]
    addresses.append(l)
    return(addresses[1:])
def parseAddress():
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    addresses=splitAddresses(data)
    for element in addresses:
        prefix=element[0][32:36]
        length_data=len(element)
        for address in element[1:]:
            if address.count(prefix)!=2:
                element.remove(address)
        new_length = len(element)
        if new_length==length_data:
            print(element[0])
        else:
            print(element[1:])
parseAddress()
```

Tried with this file

```
GROUP1:
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD47"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD48"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD70"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD71"
GROUP2:
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD47"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD48"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "XYCD70"
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "XYCD71"
```

the Output was :

```
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71"

['set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD47"\n', 'set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD48"\n']
```

you can edit the script and store infos because I did a print to show you that's works ;)

Comment: Thanks for your update, I am working on an automation tool to check config on firewall. In Firewall we create group with multiple Objects. So I am looking for a code, where I can take Group-Name as reference and check that is all group-member have a speicific WORD (4 Characters) in there name or not. If all the group members have that Word I will delete the entire Group, else I will delete the specific Members that have that speicific WORD (4 Characters) in there name

Comment: what is your input? is a text file? a json file? or just logs? it's hard to give a solution without knowing the format of your input. what I can suggest is to share a screenshot of your input and what you tried to do. So please update your question you will get a help and not a put on hold as too broad ;)

Comment: I have taken the backup in a text file and using text file as reference to create the config

Comment: So your Example A is a text file and Example B another text file ? I will update my answer ;)

Comment: We have multiple such Groups in single text file, so we need to check all the groups, so I am looking for command where we can take GROUP NAME "ABCD45-48/70-71" as reference, check all the Object name after keywork 'ADD' and check if all objects have "ABCD" in it

Comment: Thanks a Lot, This is what I needed. I will try it in my code and will share the resutls.

Comment: great ;) try to adapt the script to your use-case.

Comment: Just an addition, THis works well. But in my file I have multiple such Groups so I need to read one group name at a time and check for that. Then read next group name and check that. Can we accommodate that as well in config ??

Comment: how you make the difference between groups ? in your file there is group 1, group2 ...?

Comment: Yes all the Group have different names.

Comment: GROUP1:

set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" 
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD47" 
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "ABCD48" 
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "XYCD70" 
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/70-71" add "XYCD71"

Comment: GROUP2

set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" 

set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD47" 

set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "ABCD48" 

set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "XYCD70"
 
set group address "Private-MT" "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" add "XYCD71"

Comment: @AnkitBhargava check the last edit, I hope it's what you want

Comment: Can you please explain what is the pattern we are trying to achieve via this (pattern=re.compile("^[GROUP]+[0-9]+[:]$")), Also slight correction, Two Group has different names "ABCD45-48/70-71" and "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71".

Comment: well as you can see there is this information GROUP1, GROUP2... and between two GROUPS There is the data that we need to deal with. So to do that I used regular expression, the pattern can be used to match a string. if you can see I used firstly [GROUP] so if there is a string it should start with GROUP otherwise it isn't  the good word, this word should also contains a number because you have GROUP1,GROUP2 or another GROUP"X" so I used [0-9] and finally if after your group and the number there is a specific character like ":" you can add it like that [:]. Hope it's clear now

Comment: Got it, but slight change. Group1 and Group 2 is not the Group name. "ABCD45-48/70-71" and "ABCD45-48/XYCD70-71" is th Group names. and it can change so we need to read the line and then read the group name from it